# Unable to delete all row in Data extension using ssjs

Tags: salesforce, ssjs, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to delete rows in DE (shared DE). The code I am using is

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>test12</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script runat="server">
   Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");
   try{
    var deleteCount = DeleteData("Voucher_Notification_Threshold","return", 1)
   }catch(ex)
   {
    Write(Stringify(ex));
   }finally
   {
    Write(Stringify(deleteCount));
   }
   
  </script>
 </body>
 
</html>
```

My code (ones is complete and running) will be running as script in automation . For now i am testing it , thus i have put it cloudpages . This cloud page is also in enterprise BU and so is the Data extension from which i want to delete

I get following error :
{"message":"Object expected: DeleteData","jintException":"Jint.Native.JsException: Exception of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown.\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MethodCall methodCall)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.MethodCall.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MemberExpression expression)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(VariableDeclarationStatement statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.VariableDeclarationStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(BlockStatement statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.BlockStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(TryStatement statement)","description":"Jint.Native.JsException: Object expected: DeleteData\r\nException of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown. - from Jint\r\n\r\n"}

any clue was is causing the issue .

Answer (score 1):

first please use [StackExchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) for more reactivity on SFMC stuff.

The parameters of DeleteData function include brackets on two last parameters.

```
 <script runat="server">
            Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");
            try{
                var deleteCount = DeleteData("Voucher_Notification_Threshold",["return"], [1])
            }catch(ex)
            {
                Write(Stringify(ex));
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");
    var DE = DataExtension.Init("Voucher_Notification_Threshold");
    DE.Rows.Remove(["return"],[1]);
</script>
```